# regular expression yielding undesired result

Tags: php, regex

Here's my code:

```
$pattern = '/"([^"]*)"/' ;
$subject = '<a href="this/is/what/i/want">text_text_text</a>';
$data = preg_match($pattern, $subject, $matches);
echo $data;
```

I want to have `$data` become `this/is/what/i/want`, but when I echo it I get `1`.
My regular expression is supposed to be getting everything between the double quotes.

Can anyone shine some light on this? I'm relatively new to regex.

Comment: `preg_match()` returns 1 or 0 or FALSE, not the array. Do this instead: `preg_match(...); print_r($matches);`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `$matches`, not `$data`. `$data` holds the returnvalue of the function, which is true/false (that would be echoed as **1**/0). The 3rd parameter, `$matches`, holds the actual found matches (and a few other values processed by the function).

```
// '$data = ' is not neccesary, if you only want the matches:
preg_match($pattern, $subject, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Answer (score 1):

Many mistakes here:

1. First and foremost result of `preg_match` is just a return value not the matched result. That is available in `$matches` argument.
2. Parsing HTML with regex can be error prone.
3. You haven't shown your regex in question.

Answer (score 0):

best idea to get attribute from href is not use preg_match but objects wich do this better

```
$subject = '<a href="this/is/what/i/want">text_text_text</a>'; 

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($subject);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

$ahrefs = $xpath->query('//a');

foreach ($ahrefs as $ahref) { 
  $data = $ahref->attributes->getNamedItem("href")->nodeValue . "<br />";
} 
echo $data;
```

output:

```
 this/is/what/i/want
```